# Como faço para converter vários arquivos ".dfm" que estão no formato binário para texto?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, svn

Tenho em mãos um projeto legado que foi desenvolvido inicialmente em versões anteriores ao Delphi 7, onde o mesmo possui uma quantidade muito grande de units(.pas) e formulários(.dfm).
Estou com um problema pois como os arquivos **.dfm** estão em **formato binário** eu não consigo comparar através do *Sistemas de Controle de Versão*(Subversion) a diferença entre a versão atual do arquivo e a versão anterior. Mas convertendo esses arquivos .dfm para o **formato texto**, a partir das próximas revisões é possível fazer as comparações normalmente.

> Como faço para converter de arquivo binário para arquivo texto todos esses arquivos .dfm de uma só vez?

Obs.: Sei que é possível converter o formulário para texto através do próprio Delphi, clicando com o botão direito no formulário e escolhendo a opção *"Text DFM"*. Porém são muitos e se eu fizesse isso levaria uma eternidade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Copie o executável `CONVERT.EXE` dentro do diretório `Bin` do Delphi para o diretório que estão seus `DFM`;
- Execute o comando:

  ```
  convert.exe -t -i -s *.dfm
  ```

Answer (score 2):

```
convert -t -i -s *.dfm
```

Para todos os diretórios