# O processo de conversão de binário para .txt do Delphi é muito complexo?

Tags: c#, delphi

Em um projeto pretendo criar uma ferramenta que faria automaticamente uma "tradução" de um arquivo .dfm de Delphi para um WinForms C#.

O problema é, nem sempre os editores de DFM salvam os arquivos como texto legível, podendo as vezes salvar como binário.

Eu sei que existe uma funcionalidade de alguns editores que faz essa conversão automaticamente, mas esse processo é complexo demais para ser replicado em C#?

Gostaria de tentar implementar eu mesmo essa conversão de binário pra .txt antes de fazer o *embed* desse .exe no meu projeto ou apesar dar instruções ao usuário como fazer a conversão externamente antes de passar o .dfm pela minha ferramenta.

Comment: O que seria complexo pra vc?

Coisas que são complexas pra juniors podem não ser complexas pra seniors...

Comment: Reformulando a pergunta então, como exatamente É esta conversão?

Comment: você pega um .dfm legível, depois abre ele em um editor que escreve em binário e salve. Agora voce vai ter dois .dfm, um legível e um binário. Estude o binário para ver como voltar ao estado legível, vá anotando os passos realizados. quando terminar, faça sua ferramenta fazer os passos que voce anotou. Depois é só testar com centenas de outros .dfms em binário para ir tratando possíveis excessões

Comment: Cara dei uma pesquisada aqui e vi que tem alguns fóruns com essa questão. Não consegui ver todos devido ao proxy da empresa. Sugiro pesquisar como faz, tentar fazer e então vir com as dúvidas aqui, caso contrário a possibilidade de vc ficar no limbo é grande.

Comment: Eu dei uma rodada pela web antes de vir pro stack, a maioria dos sites descreve como fazer a conversão usando o convert.exe apenas

Comment: Há tempos atrás tive uma dúvida um pouco parecida. Talvez seja menos custoso usar o convert. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10939/como-fa%C3%A7o-para-converter-v%C3%A1rios-arquivos-dfm-que-est%C3%A3o-no-formato-bin%C3%A1rio-par